# \textcite{}: separate last and first name

Tags: biblatex

Currently when I do referencing, I have the following structure:
[image: Reference]

.bib file:

```
@ONLINE{vestacp_traffic, 
    LABEL  = {Yati, S.},
    DATE = {2016},
    TITLE   = {VESTACP PERFORMANCE ON OPENVZ VPS – A SHORT REVIEW},
    URL = {http://www.servermom.org/vestacp-performance-openvz-vps/3649/},
    URLYEAR = {2016},
    PRESORT="aa"
}
```

Everything is good until here.

However, my problem with the `\textcite{}` command.

I type: `\textcite{cite1}`, I receive the following: `Yati, S. (2016)`, however I would like it to be like this: `Yati (2016)`. Also, if I have for eg. "Google" or just simply the name of the company, NOT the last name and first name, then it should give full text.

I'm not sure how to make it in latex, but in any programming langauge I would use regex to check for the format and if it matches make what I want.

Comment: Which `biblatex` style do you use? Can you make an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows your two problems? Currently my best guess is that you have two Yatis in your `.bib` file and so `biblatex`'s disambiguation feature kicks in, try loading `biblatex` with the option `uniquename=false`.

Comment: Please note that an MWE includes the code for a full document (see also [this help link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)), and not just an entry of your `.bib` file. You should also make sure that the code you post here actually reproduces the problem your are seeing in your actual document.

Comment: It seems you have unwittingly created two different accounts: you posted as Alexander (unregistered), but edited as Alex (apparently) registered. You should probably ask Stackexchange staff to merge the two accounts to regain full control over your question http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: OK, your edit shows a different problem, don't use `label = {Yasin, S.}` use `author = {Yasin, S.}` to give the author. `label` is taken literally, while `author` will be parsed as a name and separated in first and last name. Also, why do you have `presort = {aa}`? You should also not use `urlyear`, but `urldate` and there you should always give the full access date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: If you use `author = {Yasin, S.}` you should only see the last name in citations. If you don't either you use a non-standard style that does strange things, or something else is going on (`uniquename`, for example), but in order to say something about that we need to see an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Answer (score 1):

In your example entry you use `label = {Yasin, S.}`. `label` is a fallback field in case author/editor names are missing. But I believe that in that case S. Yasin could be considered the author, so you should use

```
author = {Yasin, S.}
```

While the `label` fields are not parsed and treated like names, `author`, `editor` and `translator` are. In `\cite` commands you will normally only see the last name, except if the `uniquename` features request to see more.